# How do I find the lengths of the two legs of a right triangle if one leg is half the size of the other and I'm given the hypotenuse?

Tags: geometry

I've tried squaring the hypotenuse and then dividing up that number into 3 parts. I then give 2 of those parts to the bigger leg and one to the smaller leg. Afterward, I find the square root of each part of the hypotenuse squared. Whenever I do this, I end up with two numbers, but neither of them are half of the other.

(P.S. I'm sorry if this question is confusing to read.) (I'm not sure if I put down the right tag either. This is my first time on this website.)

Comment: Divide it up into five parts and give four to one and one to the other. If one number is twice as big as another, its square is four times as big as the other’s square.

Answer (score 1):

Let the hypotenuse be given as $h$.  Let the short leg be $x$ and the long leg be $2x$.  By the Pythagorean theorem,
\begin{align}x^2+(2x)^2&=h^2\\x^2+4x^2&=h^2\\5x^2&=h^2\\x^2&=\frac{h^2}{5}\\x&=\frac h{\sqrt 5}\end{align}

Comment: Hi Ross. Because of the level of the question, I added some of the intermediate steps to your working. I hope you don't mind.

Answer (score 0):

The proportion of the sides should be  $(1,2, \sqrt5)$. Even if not required after seeing $\sqrt 5$ was curious to find how this right triangle whose sides can be  related to the Golden Ratio $ \phi = \dfrac{\sqrt5 +1}{2}$ using Pythagorean triples... even if not asked for strictly in the question.

In the Pythagorean triplet let

$$(m^2+n^2)^2=(2mn)^2+(m^2-n^2)^2,\; \text{when} \;2mn > m^2-n^2\tag1 $$

$$2mn= 2(m^2-n^2),\; m^2-mn-n^2 =0 \tag 2 $$

Solving the quadratic,

$$ m = n \dfrac{1\pm \sqrt5}{2} = n \phi  \tag3$$

We should discard negative sign of a line segment.

Plugging  into first part of(1)

$$ n^2 \left((\phi^2+1),(\phi^2-1),2\phi \right ) \tag4$$

By the Golden Ratio property Equation (2) has the form $\; \phi^2= \phi+1$ we have

$$ n^2 \left((\phi+2), \phi, 2\phi \right ) \tag5$$

and wlog the proportion of three sides turn out related to $\phi$ as expected.

$$ \left(\phi+2, \phi, 2\phi \right ) \tag6$$

which are essentially in the proportion

$$ (\sqrt 5, 1,2). \tag7 $$

[image]